# Replace modulus by function

Tags: javascript

When I try to do `8067 % 80.67` I get `80.66999999999983`, instead of `0` beacuse of known floating point javascript behaviour.

So I went and made a function for this, to avoid floating point javascript errors.

```
function math(a, b) {

    var left = Math.abs(a),
        times = 1,
        abs = a >= 0 ? 1 : -1;

    while (Math.abs(a) >= b * times) {
        left -= b;
        times++;
    }
    return (a - (b * (times - 1))) * abs;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5w3C/

So my question is: is this usefull, ie a good tool to use instead of `%`? is there cases where this will also give falsy results like the modulus `%` oprator.
I am looking for a tools to calculate `%` consistently.

Comment: If you’re using floats, you have potential floating-point error. You could deal with it by rounding to some number of decimal places, e.g. `Math.round(8067 * 100) % Math.round(80.67 * 100) / 100`

Comment: I think you'll do better on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @minitech, thank you for feedback. Yes, that solution is often presented, but if my input has 2 more decimal cases I would need to use `10000` instead of `100` in your example, and I would like to have a "one solution" for it.

Comment: Six decimal places to a single’s precision, fifteen to a double.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the modulus operation cannot be used on a floating point. JavaScript lets you do it but doesn't work properly. Many other languages will simply fail with a compile error.

Comment: @minitech float is not accurate to six/fifteen decimal places. The accuracy depends how large the value is. With very large numbers they are both totally useless even at a single decimal place.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: “Places” as in “significant digits”.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really inspect the algorithm for correctness, but if you care about efficiency, this is a bad idea.  Basically, the larger the input, the slower your code will execute.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for feedback. Correct. Efficiency is not the issue here, its accuracy do I don't hae odd behaviours using `%`

Answer (score 0):

I think any fix will only work to a certain level of accuracy and for certain sized numbers. Perhaps something like the following will be sufficient:

```
function nearlyMod(a, b) {
  var precision = ('' + b).split('.').length;
  var estimate = (a % b).toFixed(precision);
  return estimate == b ? 0 : +estimate;
}

console.log(nearlyMod(8067, 80.66)); // 1
console.log(nearlyMod(8067, 80.67)); // 0
console.log(nearlyMod(8067, 80.68)); // 79.68
```

It tests if the result is an even divisor within the precision of the original number. If so, it returns 0, otherwise it returns a number to the same precision (which may or may not be what you want).

The result is always a number (the value returned from *toFixed* is a string, hence `+estimate`).

A better name might be "roundedMod" or similar.